# How to create an ActiveMQ Consumer without spring?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I've created an app that must consumes an activemq topic, but in this project we don't need to use spring xml. I only created one class called ActiveMQConsumer that implements MessageListener and overrides onMessage method, but nothing happens... Is this approach ok? or something missing? I'm currently connecting through tcp.

```
public class ActiveMQConsumer implements MessageListener {

public ActiveMQConsumer() throws JMSException {
    try {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(CATALOG_BROKER_URL.getValue());
        Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createTopic(CATALOG_TOPIC_NAME.getValue());
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        consumer.setMessageListener(this);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(final Message message) {
    LOGGER.info("Start consuming message from Catalog");
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Message: " + txtMessage.getText());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Message !");
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How is that class used? Are you doing `new ActiveMQConsumer()` somewhere? Is it annotated with `@Component` so spring does that? Just writing a class does not mean that it's used at runtime. maybe related: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

Comment: @zapl i don't want to use spring, i saw some examples that dont need it... how can i do it?

Comment: Ah, ok. Spring is not required. Does your code run without exception and have you verified that it establishes a connection? And is there anything publishing messages?

Comment: after running your programme , if in your activeMQ UI you are able to see 'no of consumer' as 1 against that topic ,then you can be sure that your consumer is running properly and there is some different problem, but if consumer doesnt get registered there , you need to have a look on how your consumer is executing

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem using an ContextListener to call an runnable class. Just put it into web.xml and done.